# Doing for loop computations faster

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, optimization

I have a for loop doing some operation on the elements of an array. There are 1e5 elements in the array

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([1,2,3,4..........100000)]
for i in range(0,len(A)):
       A[i]=(A[i]*2+A[i]*4)**(1/3)
```

I want to obtain parallelisation in the above code so that each execution of the for loop goes to a different core to make the code execution faster. I have a workstation with 48 cores. How to achieve this parallel processing in python? Please help.

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes: I assume they were hand waving away the precise values, and typoed the order of the close paren/bracket. You could achieve the same result with `np.arange(1, 100000+1)` (much more quickly) if you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't bother parallelizing just yet. Right now, you're taking *no* advantage of `numpy` vectorization; you may as well be using Python `list` (or maybe `array.array`) for all the benefit `numpy` is giving you.

Actually use the vectorization features, and the overhead should drop by several orders of magnitude:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1,2,3,4..........100000])  # If this is actually the values you want, use np.arange(1, 100000+1) to speed it up
A = (A * 6) ** (1 / 3)

# If the result should truncate back to int64, not convert to doubles, cast back at the end
A = A.astype(np.int64)
```

`(A * 6) ** (1 / 3)` does the same work as the `for` loop did, but *much* faster (you could match the original code more closely with `A = (A * 2 + A * 4) ** (1/3)`, but multiplying by `2` and `4` separately and adding them together is pointless when you could just multiply by `6` directly). The final (optional, depending on intent) line gets exact equivalent behavior of the original loop by truncating back to the original integer `dtype`.

Comparing performance with `ipython` `%%timeit` magic for a microbenchmark:

```
In [2]: %%timeit
   ...: A = np.arange(1, 100000+1)
   ...: for i in range(len(A)):
   ...:     A[i] = (A[i]*2 + A[i]*4) ** (1/3)
   ...:
427 ms ± 6.49 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [3]: %%timeit
   ...: A = np.arange(1, 100000+1)
   ...: A = (A * 6) ** (1/3)
   ...:
2.72 ms ± 51 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The vectorized code takes about 0.6% of the time taken by the naive loop; merely parallelizing the naive loop would never come *close* to achieving that sort of speedup. Adding the `.astype(np.int64)` cast only increases runtime by about 6%, still a trivial fraction of what the original `for` loop required.

Comment: Will using `A = np.power(A*6, 1/3)` have any improvement?

Comment: @anurag: You're welcome to try, but it shouldn't make a difference; the `numpy` `array` type almost certainly overloads `__pow__` (the special method invoked by `**`) to do the same thing, so unless you need to tweak behaviors with the optional arguments to `numpy.power`, there's no real benefit (it would likely be *slightly* slower by using generic function call dispatch, rather than dedicated syntax-based dispatch, but the difference would be meaningless for moderate sized arrays). Local tests showed them roughly equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Let numpy do the hard work.

```
A = (A*2+A*4)**(1/3)
```